# Removing specific values when a certain value is before

Tags: python

I have a.csv file that has values that will distort my calculation

**Approach**

I want to remove values that exits on rows after specific values in each row, for example, if there is a "(B)" on a row and it's the first before "(D)" and others "(B)" only keep the first "(B)"

And same for "+", "++" and "+++", i want to keep only the first one in each line

**Desired result**

```
1277|2013-12-17 16:00:00|100|+|
1360|2014-01-15 16:00:00|(B)|99|++|E
1402|2014-02-05 20:00:00|(D)|99|++|D
1360|2014-01-29 08:00:00|(D)|99|C
1378|2014-01-21 20:00:00|(B)|100||D
```

**Sample of the csv file :**

```
1277|2013-12-17 16:00:00|100|+|++|
1360|2014-01-15 16:00:00|(B)|(D)|99|++|+++||+|E
1402|2014-02-05 20:00:00|(D)|(B)|99|++|+||D
1360|2014-01-29 08:00:00|(D)|(B)|99||C
1378|2014-01-21 20:00:00|(B)|100||D
```

Comment: Your output looks inconsistent - on the second through fourth lines you remove the empty elements, but you don't remove them on the last line. What should be the rule about that?

Comment: The rule will be to delete the empty elements because it's useless

Comment: On stackoverflow, you're supposed to show us what you've tried to do first.

Comment: @MaximeChéramy  I corrected the post as you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short little program that takes a list of tuples `invalid_together` and removes values as you described in the question. It just iterates through the data, and once it finds a value in an invalid grouping, it removes all following values in that group

```
import csv

invalid_together = [
    ('+', '++', '+++'),
    ('(A)', '(B)', '(C)', '(D)')
]

removeAll = ['']

with open('data.csv', 'rt') as dataIn:
    with open('new_data.csv', 'w') as dataOut:
        reader = csv.reader(dataIn, delimiter="|")
        writer = csv.writer(dataOut, delimiter="|")
        for row in reader:
            for invalidGroup in invalid_together:
                foundInvalid = False
                offset = 0
                for index in range(0, len(row)):
                    item = row[index - offset]
                    if item in invalidGroup and not(foundInvalid):
                        foundInvalid = True
                    elif (item in invalidGroup and foundInvalid) or (item in removeAll):
                        row.pop(index - offset)
                        offset += 1
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: i have tried the program it retunrnig me an error :  line 92, in <module>
    for row in reader:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: The encoding of your file must be different from mine. Try opening the CSVs with 'rt' and 'wt' to not use bytes

Comment: it worked well for the letters but not for the "+" values

Comment: Sorry but I'd need more information to help. I copied your example into a csv and ran this fine in python 2.7, so I need to know a bit more

Comment: The program works but the values "+", "++" and "+++" are still followed by one of the values "+", "++" or "+++"
like this : 3030|2015-09-22 12:00:00|++|+++|
and i'm using python 3.6

Comment: I've modified the code in my answer. Python treats the lists differently when reading it in as a text file instead of binary, that was most likely what was causing you issues

Comment: I have this problem now 
line : writer.writerow(row)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: This should now become a new question. Your original question has been answered, so mark an answer and ask a new one, your problem now is different. This is a problem with whether you open the file with 'rt' or 'rb' and 'wt' or 'wb', aka whether you're using strings or bytes

Comment: I find the problem i just had to change `with open('new_data.csv', 'wb') as dataOut:` to `with open('new_data.csv', 'w') as dataOut:` Python 3 csv takes the input in text mode, whereas in Python 2 it took it in binary mode.
Thank very much for your help :)

Comment: Ah great, modified the answer to show that. Btw in the future there is a python-3.x tag which helps avoid these issues of answers in 2.7 vs 3. Glad it's working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `csv` module to read one CSV, then filter each of its rows to not include repeated elements of the same *category* and finally write everything down as a new CSV. First create a *category* filter:

```
categories = [  # make a list of tuples containing elements that should appear only once
    ("(B)", "(D)"),
    ("+", "++", "+++")
]

categories_map = {e: c[0] for c in categories for e in c}  # turn it into a quick lookup map

def filter_elements(row):  # and then build your filters
    unique = set()  # a set to hold our unique values
    for column in row:
        if column in categories_map:
            if categories_map[column] not in unique:
                unique.add(categories_map[column])
                yield column
        elif column:  # use `else:` instead if you want to keep the empty fields
            yield column
```

Finally, open your input CSV, read it, filter its rows and immediately write it to the output CSV:

```
with open("in.csv", "r", newline="") as f_in, open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter="|")  # create a CSV writer
    for row in csv.reader(f_in, delimiter="|"):  # iterate over a CSV reader
        writer.writerow(c for c in filter_elements(row))  # filter + write to the out.csv
```

For your posted example data, this will produce `out.csv` containing:

```
1277|2013-12-17 16:00:00|100|+
1360|2014-01-15 16:00:00|(B)|99|++|E
1402|2014-02-05 20:00:00|(D)|99|++|D
1360|2014-01-29 08:00:00|(D)|99|C
1378|2014-01-21 20:00:00|(B)|100|D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to extract desired parts:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^(.* \d+:\d+:\d+(?=\|))\|(\(\S\)(?=|))?.*?(\d+)\|(\++)?.*?\|(\S)?$')

with open('data.csv', 'r') as infile:
    with open('result.csv', 'w')  as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write('|'.join(str(x) for x in pattern.match(line).groups() if x) + '\n')
```

This will result in:

```
1277|2013-12-17 16:00:00|100|+
1360|2014-01-15 16:00:00|(B)|99|++|E
1402|2014-02-05 20:00:00|(D)|99|++|D
1360|2014-01-29 08:00:00|(D)|99|C
1378|2014-01-21 20:00:00|(B)|100|D
```

If you want to post-process the output, probably it would be better to keep constant amount of elements per line instead of skipping elements which were empty. In order to do that, you can replace the last line with:

```
outfile.write('|'.join(str(x) for x in pattern.match(line).groups()) + '\n')
```

which will give as an output:

```
1277|2013-12-17 16:00:00|None|100|+|None
1360|2014-01-15 16:00:00|(B)|99|++|E
1402|2014-02-05 20:00:00|(D)|99|++|D
1360|2014-01-29 08:00:00|(D)|99|None|C
1378|2014-01-21 20:00:00|(B)|100|None|D
```

**Edit:**

In order to catch lines like:

```
325|2014-01-18 20:00:00|(B)|93|++|+||Calme
```

the pattern can be modified to:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^(.* \d+:\d+:\d+(?=\|))\|(\(\S\)(?=|))?.*?(\d+)\|(\++)?.*\|(\S+)?\s*?$')
```

You can quickly verify it [here](https://regex101.com/r/PAASJK/1), also for the rest of the lines on which it initially failed.

Comment: It worked for the letters but it kept the following '+', '++ or '+++' for 28 rows on 650000 rows

Comment: can you provide here one (or more) of the rows on which it had failed?

Comment: yes of course here is the an example of the rows that failed `325|2014-01-18 20:00:00|(B)|93|++|+||Calme
`

Comment: Check the edit. This pattern will catch all provided examples.